# Personal Names Turn Around

Tags: geometry, connect-wall, cellular-automata

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #8: Cellular Automata](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/monthly-topic-challenge-8-cellular-automata).</sub>

---

Life is like [connecting dots](http://www.dotsies.org/#)...

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **ACE** | **BTS** | **GKH** | **HE** |
| **I** | **II** | **ING** | **LOAF** |
| **ME** | **MOON** | **POND** | **PV** |
| **QR** | **ROT** | **TUB** | **US** |

---

Can you identify the themes? Here is a hint:

> One theme is related to [Dotsies](http://www.dotsies.org/#) *and* the MTC theme.
>  Another theme is related to Dotsies but not the MTC theme.
>  The third theme is related to the MTC but not Dotsies.
>  The last theme is neither Dotsies nor MTC.

Answer (score 5):

Related to the MTC but not Dotsies

> Names of [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) still-life patterns
>  [POND](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Pond),
>  [TUB](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/tub),
>  [LOAF](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/loaf),
>  [BTS](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/BTS)

Related to Dotsies but not the MTC theme

> The dots of the words when written in Dotsies each have a diagonally opposite pair.
> E.g. `[2,1]=[W-1,H]`
>  ACE, ROT, MOON, PV
>  [image]

Related to Dotsies and the MTC theme

> Dotsie words that form a still-life in GOL.
>  GKH, II, QR, ING
>  [image]

Neither Dotsies nor MTC

> Personal Pronouns
>  I, ME, HE, US